# JOptionPane error on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, computer-science, joptionpane

I am VERY new to Java (ie week 2 of AP Computer Science A). we have to use JOptionPane to make message boxes to use with math operations. My code was fine at school but I had to reformat it because I saved it on Facebook (no other option). Now I get errors on all the JOptionPane lines saying "Multiple markers at this line" and " Syntax error on tokens".
How do I fix that. here is the code (please only fix what I am asking, nothing else, I know the code is probably weird)

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OptioPane {

public static void main(String[] args) {    
}

    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer");
    String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input another");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(b);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDiaglog(null, "The numbers added together is " +(x+y));

    String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer");
    String d = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input another");
    int f = Integer.parseInt(c);
    int g = Integer.parseInt(d);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The second number subtracted from the first number is " +(f-g));

    String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer");
    String r = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input another");
    int w = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int q = Integer.parseInt(b);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The numbers multiplied together is " +(w*q));

    String k = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer");
    String j = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input another");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int m = Integer.parseInt(b);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The first number divided by the second number is " +(n/m));

    String fir = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer");
    String tir = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input another");
    int ah = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int bh = Integer.parseInt(b);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The first number modulated by the second number is " +(ah*bh));
    }
```

Comment: Be careful which variables you're using in each case. You've got several lines like `int w = Integer.parseInt(a);` where `a` should really be `s` or some other variable.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the body of your code is out side of any executable context (not where it belongs)....

```
public class OptioPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    }

    /* All your stuff - out of bounds and behaving badly */

}
```

Instead, you need to place this code within a executable context, such as the `main` method...

```
public class OptioPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        /* All your stuff - playing nicely */
    }


}
```

Oh, add the this line...

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDiaglog(null, "The numbers added together is " +(x+y));
```

Is wrong, see the extra `g` in `Dialog`, it should be...

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The numbers added together is " +(x+y));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you did something wrong while re-formatting the code because the entire code block should be inside the curly braces of the main method

Comment: this fixed it! only problem is that my multiplication comes out wrong. for example 5 times 5 comes out to 30...

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment about multiplication and if you still have problems with it, it's because of this

```
  String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer");
    String r = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input another");
    int w = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int q = Integer.parseInt(b);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The numbers multiplied together is " +(w*q));
```

when you input 5 into 's' and 5 into 'r' and get 30, you probably had 5 and 6 in 'a' and 'b' respectively.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Dialogue1 {

    public static void main(String[]arg)
    {
        String number1,number2;
        number1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter first number");
        number2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter second number");
        int num1=Integer.parseInt(number1);
        int num2=Integer.parseInt(number2);
        int sum=num1+num2;
        String message=String.format("the sum is %d",sum);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,sum);
    }
}
```

Store your result in another variable and then display it. It will work for sure without any error.

Answer (score -1):

If you face any issue I guess there are some suggestions given below the error in Eclipse. I have also encountered the same error it suggested me to import the java swing package then it got fixed.